# FFMPEG - Crop and Chromakey not working together?

Tags: ffmpeg, chromakey, scale

Having an issue with the chromakey portion not working after the scale. Any ideas?

ffmpeg -i background1080.png -i file.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=1612:906[inner];[0][inner]overlay=154:170; [1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.02:0.03[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -y -b:v 2000k -b:a 192k -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=20:scenecut=0 -acodec copy file_FINAL.mp4

Comment: So this crops but the chroma-key doesn't work. If I remove the crop, the chroma key works - I think I'm just not understanding the syntax relationship fully for the [out] commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you reference the input file two times.

```
[1]scale=1612:906[inner];[0][inner]overlay=154:170;[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.02:0.03[ckout]
```

what you actually want is to use the scaled version. so:

```
[1]scale=1612:906[inner];[0][inner]overlay=154:170[ovout]; [ovout]colorkey=0x000000:0.02:0.03[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]
```

But I don't really understand why you overlay the image twice...
wouldn't this work?

```
[1]colorkey=0x000000:0.02:0.03[ckout];[ckout]scale=1612:906[scaleout];[0][scaleout]overlay=154:170[out];
```

1. colorkey, 2. scale, 3. overlay

You should almost always colorkey first and then scale to reduce colorkey artifacts

Greetings